# How can I preserve the last frame of an animation such that it doesn't return to the default position after executing?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I'm trying to make an animation keep the last frame when it plays so it does not go back to the default position.

This is the code I've got:

```
local animation = script:WaitForChild('Dead')
local humanoid = script.Parent:WaitForChild('Humanoid')
local dead = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
dead:play()
print("Playedw")
wait(1)
animation:AdjustSpeed(0)
print("It works")
```

And this is the error I get

> AdjustSpeed is not a valid member of Animation "Workspace.Female.Script.Dead"

How can I get this working so it doesn't return back to the default position?

Answer (score 2):

Do `dead:AdjustSpeed(0)`, it will pause the loaded animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop an animation.

However, you could try using a second looping animation so that it is always in the same position, that plays after the first death animation finishes.